# Server Hangup messges

Tags: web-server, perl, hanging

First question on Server Fault! (If I have done anything wrong let me know)

I manage a server and also the 3 large perl based web applications, which run on this server.

The server is running CentOS 7.2 SELinux with Apache running on top of it.
(For background, the applications were running on an old redhat server until we recently migrated over.) The users of the application have started to report the following error:

SERVER HANGUP
Description: Server Hangup

The error is simply the text above being returned. Doesn't look like an apache or application error message.

The error isn't replicable and seems to occur randomly (as in, on random pages, at random times).

We tested the speed of the connections to the server and there is an issue there, though the hosting company says we aren't throttled, and the settings when I run the ethtool program shows there is no throttling in place. and duplex is running in full mode.

My theory is that as there is some network throttling somewhere, and that this is causing the issue the users are reporting. At points when more users are using the system it could 'hang up'

I have never seen this issue before nor can find any documentation or help online with this error.

If anyone has had experience of this any help would be appreciated

Thanks